# Giving error when use res.redirect in passport google auth strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

Route.js

```
router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

router.get('/auth/google/callback', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('google', {}, (err, token, info) => {
    if (info) {
        console.log(info)
        req.data = info
        req.status = 200
        req.message = 'User Logged in Succcessfully'
        res.redirect('https://www.google.com')   // If I comment this it does not show error
        next()
    }
    else {
        req.data = null
        req.status = 403
        return (next(new Error('Unauthorized')))
    }
 })(req, res, next)
})
```

I am using google strategy and its working fine but if I redirect it to some URL using res.redirect() then it shows error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". What I want to return info and redirect it to the website after successful auth. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: after `res.redirect` the request ends. `next()` is not doing anything and probably raising the error

Comment: I tried removing next also nothing happens

Comment: try also removing `(req, res, next)` from the end of `passport.authenticate`. it's reachable from within the route.

Comment: Yup removing next worked today error is not showing but I want to send res also due to res.redirect I am not able to use next. How can I send info in res now